# Spring security db UserDetailsService doesn't take in account the roles of users

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

I have a toy web app, in which I want to login the users taken from database.

It works but, I can login with a USER role where I should only login with a user having the ADMIN role.

Here is my code:

Servlet 3.0 bootstraper

```
public class Bootstraper extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{JPAConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"), new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()};
    }
}
```

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private boolean enabled;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String password, boolean enabled) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", enabled=" + enabled +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Role entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String role;

    @JoinColumn(name = "u_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", role='" + role + '\'' +
                ", user=" + user +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My custome userdetailsservice:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = usersService.getUser(username);
        if (user != null) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = user.getRoles().stream()
                    .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorityList);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I am keeping my roles in the db, as strings : USER, MODERATOR, ADMIN

My Spring security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll().and()
                .logout().permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

The problem is guys, that I said I want every user to have the ROLE_ADMIN but I am still able to login also with a user that has only the USER role. I don't understand why.

I have made debug, my user is fetched successfully from the db, all is fine,but I don't know where Spring is checking for roles.

Regards,

Comment: Enable the debug logging( log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG, stdout, fileout - for log4j) it will tell you a lot.

Comment: Please change `ROLE_ADMIN` to `ADMIN` and try.

Comment: @Mithun the access function does not require "ROLE_". See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove your `.anyRequest().authenticated()` from configuration since if you request ROLE checking user has to be authenticated it apparently takes precedence when checked by the security filter

Comment: I also had to add ROLE_ to my roles got from database, but it works now. If I let the line you mentioned, then I can authenticate with every role anywhere, so you where right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as user3030447 said in a comment:

Roles must start with ROLE_*.

e.g. if you want to use `hasRole('EDIT')` you will have to create the GrantedAuthority like this:

```
new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_EDIT");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasAuthority()` or `hasAnyAuthority()` functions.