# Spring `@RolesAllowed` ignored?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, vaadin

Ok, so I have a Vaadin application (Vaadin 8 for legacy reasons), that I am integrating with Spring Security.

This works perfectly fine and non-admin users get an access denied:

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@SpringView(name = AdminHomeView.NAME)
class AdminHomeView : View, VerticalLayout(){
    companion object {
        const val NAME = "admin/home"
    }

    @PostConstruct
    internal fun init(){
        val label = Label()
        label.id = "label.msg"
        label.value = "This is the protected admin section. You are authenticated and authorized."

        this.addComponents(
                label
        )
    }
}
```

But if I replace the `@Secured` with `@RolesAllowed`, the annotation gets ignored and non-admin users can access the view.

This is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableVaadin
@EnableVaadinSharedSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true, 
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        proxyTargetClass = true
)
class VaadinAwareSecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService

    @Inject
    constructor(userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) : super() {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService
    }


    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .csrf().disable() //vaadin has its own csrf protection, therefore this must be disabled
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler())
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?goodbye").permitAll()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
    }

    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
        web
            .ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/VAADIN/**"
            )
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {

        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    }

    private fun logoutHandler():LogoutHandler{
        return VaadinSessionClosingLogoutHandler()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder(12)
    }

    @Bean
    fun myAuthenticationManager():AuthenticationManager{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you tried suggestions here? [Spring security db UserDetailsService doesn't take in account the roles of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175411/spring-security-db-userdetailsservice-doesnt-take-in-account-the-roles-of-users)

Comment: @anasmi No. That's a completely different issue.

Comment: Noticed that too, it should not make any difference indeed :/